# retain dropdown values in javascript after the page is reloaded

Tags: javascript

I am having two dropdowns , in which the second dropdown will be populated only after i select something from the first drop down. if the page is refreshedafter ajax_update the second drop down does not show the previously selected choice ??? How to do this in javascript?

Comment: Please post some code showing what you've tried so far. You're much more likely to get answers this way :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of choices for this.  My suggestion would be to use the localStorage API to store the choice from the first dropdown.  Then on page load, look to see if you have a value stored, and if you do, populate the first dropdown and call its change event to populate the second.

Have a look here for information on localStorage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#localStorage